# woocommerce theme nline styles are not working in IE 9 browser

Tags: css, wordpress, styles, woocommerce

I have developed on one project in woocommerce.It's working fine in all browsers 
But that is not working in IE9 browser.

I don't know no clearly about that.I think there is a restriction to stop that style in IE9
how to remove that 
can you please tel me that one to me

thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for "*if gt IE*" or "*if lt IE*" lines in the source code of the page. They might be attached to the inline css. If so check the theme **header.php** and find where it generates the inline css.

Also the theme might use a specific IE css file that overrides the inline styles by using "*!important*" declarations.

Hope this helped!